# How to prove the following inequality

Tags: inequality

How to show this inequality:

$1.3.5...(2n-1)<n^n$

the inequality is satisfied for $n=2$

Now proving by induction

$1.3.5...(2n-1)(2n+1)<n^n.(2n+1)$

but the RHS can't be made less than $(n+1)^{n+1}=(n+1)^n.(n+1)$

Obviously $n^n<(n+1)^n$ but $2n+1$ is not less than $n+1$.Any help

Comment: Perhaps you meant $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1) < n^n$, i.e. the product of the first $n$ odd numbers ?

Comment: @Neeraj: Did you edit the question based on what OP *could* have meant? It is a completely different question now. Also you have removed OP's attempt to solve the question, so that it looks like a bad question now.

Comment: Yeah there's was an error so I edited it to the correct problem.

Comment: @martinr that makes more sense. The lhs was blowing up way to fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **AM-GM** as follows $$\frac{1+3+\cdots +(2n-1)}{n}\ge \left(1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)\right)^{1/n}$$ then $$\frac{n^2}{n}\ge \left(1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)\right)^{1/n}$$ gives $$n^n\ge \left(1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is false for $n=2$. The left side is equal to $1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 6$, and the right side is equalt to $2^2=4$.

Answer (score 0):

A proof by induction will probably not work here. But can obtain the result
quite easily by combining factors from "both ends" of the product with
the third binomial formula:

$$
  1 \cdot 3 = (2-1)\, (2+1) = 2^2 - 1^2 < 2^2 \\
  1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = (3-2) \, 3 \, (3+1) = (3^2 - 1^2) \, 3 < 3^3 \\
  1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = (4-3)\,(4-1)\,(4+1)\,(4+3) = (4^2 - 3^3)\,(4^2 - 1^2) < 4^4 \\
  \ldots
$$
This should show the idea how the inequality can be proved in general.